# How can I export/save a playlist in gmusicbrowser?

Tags: playlists, gmusicbrowser

- Xubuntu 14.04
- gmusicbrowser 1.1.13.1

I'd like to transfer my playlists from gmusicbrowser to Banshee. For this I'd like to export the playlists in gmusicbrowser. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

1. Open the **settings**
2. Go to the **Plugins** tab
3. Set the check mark for the **export** plugin
4. Go back to your library
5. Mark/highlight the tracks you want to select for export
6. With the right mouse button, click on one of the track you selected and then click on **export to m3u-file**